# The variable type of the foreignId field return as a string, not an integer | Laravel | Migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

community,

I am working on the Laravel application where I had created the policy for the resource and everything is working according to the expectation on my local server. But I got a very tricky issue when I move my code on the production. When I try to delete or update the resource then it shows me the "403 | This action is unauthorized." error page. but on the local, I didn't have any kind of this issue.

After the echo, a print statement that I come to know that the type of the field that is created using foreignId(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns) is a "string" not a "integer".

Let me clear some structure here. A user can create clients and do CRUD operations on their clients only.

**client_migration.php**

```
class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            // other fields
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        })
    }
}
```

**ClientPolicy.php**

```
class ClientPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Client  $client
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Client $client)
    {
        echo gettype($user->id).", ".gettype($client->user_id); // it echos integer, string
        die;
        return $user->id === $client->user_id;
    }
}
```

As you can see I use === operator instead of == because I expect the return type of foreign and primary key will be the same(which is working on my local) but the type of foreign key is a string.

I know there is the solution to just replace === operator to == but I need to know the actual issue.

Comment: When you pass data via request, number will convert to string. `1` will be "`1"`

Comment: Make it integer `gettype((int)$client->user_id);`

Comment: @STA I know the possible solution. One simple solution is to just change the operator(==). But why the same thing working on my local where the type is an integer, not a string. As per you say, request convert number to string then why this not happened on my local server.

Comment: Dont know the reson, but here the last answer also convert it to (int) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-policy-is-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Please also read this one https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-collection-returns-an-int-as-string-locally-and-on-live-enviroment-as-string

Comment: What version of mysql do you run locally? what package did you install it from?

Comment: On the live server it is "10.3.22-MariaDB-cll-lve" and on the local server "10.3.16-MariaDB" and I didn't use any package for the policy. it is coming with laravel.